# Makefile does not find Qt5 headers with pkg-config

Tags: qt, qt5, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile [this](https://github.com/FreeSpacenav/spnavcfg) application.
I installed Qt5 from the Qt online installer inside my home directory.
Then I symlinked the pkgconfig files in `/usr/local/share/pkgconfig`.
When I issue `make` in the project directory, it finds now the packages but it does not find the headers:

```
$ make
g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -g -O3 -I. -I/usr/local/include -fPIC `pkg-config --cflags Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets`  -MMD   -c -o src/main.o src/main.cc
src/main.cc:18:10: fatal error: QApplication: no such file or directory
   18 | #include <QApplication>
```

So I updated the make file, adding the actual directory for the include files:

```
incpath = -I. -I$(PREFIX)/include -I/home/mark/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/include
libpath = -L$(PREFIX)/lib -L/home/mark/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib
```

But the output is the same:

```
$ make
g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -g -O3 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/home/mark/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/include -fPIC `pkg-config --cflags Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets`  -MMD   -c -o src/main.o src/main.cc
src/main.cc:18:10: fatal error: QApplication: no such file or directory
   18 | #include <QApplication>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<incorporato>: src/main.o] Errore 1
```

It's not a `qmake` project, hence I don't have any .pro file to edit.

What am I missing?

### EDIT

```
$ ls /home/mark/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/include
Qt3DAnimation             QtEglFSDeviceIntegration     QtPacketProtocol             QtSerialBus
Qt3DCore                  QtEglSupport                 QtPlatformCompositorSupport  QtSerialPort
Qt3DExtras                QtEventDispatcherSupport     QtPlatformHeaders            QtServiceSupport
Qt3DInput                 QtFbSupport                  QtPositioning                QtSql
Qt3DLogic                 QtFontDatabaseSupport        QtPositioningQuick           QtSvg
Qt3DQuick                 QtGamepad                    QtPrintSupport               QtTest
Qt3DQuickAnimation        QtGlxSupport                 QtQml                        QtTextToSpeech
Qt3DQuickExtras           QtGui                        QtQmlDebug                   QtThemeSupport
Qt3DQuickInput            QtHelp                       QtQmlModels                  QtUiPlugin
Qt3DQuickRender           QtInputSupport               QtQmlWorkerScript            QtUiTools
Qt3DQuickScene2D          QtKmsSupport                 QtQuick                      QtVulkanSupport
Qt3DRender                QtLinuxAccessibilitySupport  QtQuickControls2             QtWaylandClient
QtAccessibilitySupport    QtLocation                   QtQuickParticles             QtWebChannel
QtBluetooth               QtMultimedia                 QtQuickShapes                QtWebSockets
QtConcurrent              QtMultimediaGstTools         QtQuickTemplates2            QtWebView
QtCore                    QtMultimediaQuick            QtQuickTest                  QtWidgets
QtDBus                    QtMultimediaWidgets          QtQuickWidgets               QtX11Extras
QtDesigner                QtNetwork                    QtRemoteObjects              QtXkbCommonSupport
QtDesignerComponents      QtNfc                        QtRepParser                  QtXml
QtDeviceDiscoverySupport  QtOpenGL                     QtScxml                      QtXmlPatterns
```

and

```
$ pkg-config --cflags Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets
-DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/qt/work/install/include/QtWidgets -I/home/qt/work/install/include -I/home/qt/work/install/include/QtGui -I/home/qt/work/install/include -I/home/qt/work/install/include/QtCore -I/home/qt/work/install/include
```

Not sure what is `qt/work`. I don't have this directory in my machine.

Comment: What is the full output of `ls /home/mark/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/include` and `pkg-config --cflags Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets`?

Comment: As you can see, `gcc_64/include` does not offer a file named `QApplication`. 
Also your Qt installation's pkgconfig file is simply wrong. It is not supposed to be used. (Note how you installed in your home but link to the file from a system directory)

I suggest you install Qt5 through your distribution. On Mac I recommend homebrew.

Comment: If you were to patch the Makefile to work with your current installation, you would need to include `-I/home/mark/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I/home/mark/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/home/mark/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets`, but my recommendation still stands. Otherwise you would need additional changes to make the dynamic linking work as well...

Comment: @ypnos I asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455835/which-packages-install-qt5-pkg-config-files which packages should I use

Comment: On Debian-based distributions, including Ubuntu, you need to install `-dev` packages for compiling stuff on your own. For you, `qtbase5-dev` might already be enough.